# .net mvc 4.5 - add required" attribute to data model at runtime

Tags: asp.net, validation, model

I have this Data Transfer Model:

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
class PersonDTO {

    [DataMember(Name="id")]
    public int id { get; set; }


    [DataMember(Name="name")]
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }


}
```

I want to be able to use this model for both Create and Update operations. The issue here is that when creating a new Person, its id doesn't exist yet (hence the missing [Required] annotation). While updating however, the id exists already, and needs to be a required field.

In my controller, I have these operations:

```
public class PersonController {

    [HttpPut]
    public void UpdatePerson(PersonDTO person) {}

    [HttpPost]
    public void CreatePerson(PersonDTO person) {}

}
```

Is there a way to use the same DTO for both operations, but make the field 'id' required for one of them, so ModelState fails? I know I can do it manually by checking `person.id == null`, but I'm looking for an automatic solution, if exists.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need help on this, but I stumbled across your question because I was searching for a similar answer. I've just worked out a simple way to achieve what you're looking for. It's cheating a bit, but it works.

In the page markup, simply add "data_val_required" to the style of the field in question, followed by the error message you want.

For example:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.OldPassword, 
                           new { data_val_required="The Old Password field is required." })
```

The client side validators pick this up and display the appropriate message in the validation summary.

On the server side, you MUST remember to validate your model in code and manually check the content of the field, as you cannot rely on the client side validation to work (JavaScript could have been disabled, for example.)

The reason I wanted to do this is in a Change Password page. My model contains three fields:

1. Old Password
2. New Password [Required]
3. Confirm Password [Required]

The Old Password is only required if the user is making their own decision to change their password. If I'm forcing a user to reset his/her password (because they lost their old one), then the Old Password should not be required (since they don't know it!)

So I have some code in the client side to emit "data_val_required" if the user is changing their password on their own volition, and remove the entire field if not.

I also have the code in the server-side to check both scenarios too.

Hope this helps you.